# Why CMake cannot find my Boost libraries on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake, ubuntu-18.04

This is driving me nuts. In my `CMakeLists.txt` I have:

`find_package(Boost 1.63.0 REQUIRED SYSTEM)`

Result:

```
[0/1] Re-running CMake...
Build type: Release
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1947 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.65.1

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_system
```

But:

```
$ locate libboost_system
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.65.1
```

And:

```
$ sudo apt install libboost-all-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libboost-all-dev is already the newest version (1.65.1.0ubuntu1).
```

I have previously used a self-compiled `1.63.0`, but I have removed all the files from `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`. Maybe it still somehow haunts here..?

If I find Boost like this (without system):

`find_package(Boost 1.63.0 REQUIRED)`

..then configuring succeeds, but won't link to `${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}`:

```
/usr/bin/ld: src/app/CMakeFiles/app.dir/application.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.65.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you should require `system` instead of `SYSTEM` even though it complains about missing `boost_system` also when `SYSTEM` was used. I find that a **bit** confusing:

`find_package(Boost 1.63.0 REQUIRED system)`